# Given two matricies of transition rates or default rates, quantitatively evaluate the quality control or methodology used by the two rating agencies

Tags: math, matrix, statistics, controls, default

Given two matrices of transition or default rate on the same group of companies, provided by two rating agencies.

How do I show quantitatively that the two rating agencies are both applying similar methodology or have similar quality controls in place.

So if they are using similar methods to rate these companies, I would expect the default rates given to the group of companies to be similar from both rating agencies.

I remember coming across a somewhat similar problem in my statistics class, where we are asked to show that the quality control of two factories are similar given the defect rates. Does anyone have any idea?

[Here is the first matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27k4R.png)

[Here is the send matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLlik.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: I am guessing you want to find out whether the ratings given by one company are **correlated** with the ratings given by the other company? Without context it's a bit difficult to understand how those default rates and transition matrix you talk about work together, so we can't really answer whether those matrices come from "a similar methodology or similar quality controls".

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark The issue will later become a programming problem, when we have multiple matrices, but first I wanted to see whats the best approach to the topic.